# Is there a nested if in lisp?

Tags: if-statement, nested, lisp, structure

```
(if (> 10 5)
    (format t "First number is greater ~%"))
    
    (if (> 10 15) 
        (format t "First number is greater ~%")
        (format t "Second number is greater ~%"))
        
        (if (= 10 10)
        (format t "Both numbers are equal"))
```

Comment: Is [`cond`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm) what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure because the syntax is quite confusing. I was comparing it to C Language's Nested if and I was wondering if there is an alternative or equivalent in LISP

Comment: Lisp nested `IF` is just like C nested `if`. You can use `if` anywhere that any expression is allowed, including inside another `if`.

Comment: Why do you print `First number is greater` in the second case where 10 is not greater than 15?

Comment: Btw you are not nesting the ones in your question, just indenting them so that they appear nested.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `if` in most Lisps is `(if <test> <then> [<else>])` although there may be some variation: sometimes the `<else>` is mandatory, and in some older lisps there can be many forms for `<else>` (I think elisp is the only commonly-used lisp where that is the case now).  So a nested `if` is simple:

```
(if a
    ...
  (if b
      ...
    (if c
        ...
      ...)))
```

This is annoying in terms of indentation, so there is a form called `cond` in which the above expression would be, in Common Lisp:

```
(cond
 (a ...)
 (b ...)
 (c ...)
 (t ...))
```

or in Scheme

```
(cond
 (a ...)
 (b ...)
 (c ...)
 (else ...))
```

`cond` has the nice feature that all the `...`s can be many forms.

If you didn't have `cond` you could write it in terms of `if`: here's a version using Scheme's macros (actually Racket's: `void` is Racket I think), called `kond`:

```
(define-syntax kond
  (syntax-rules (else)
    [(_)
     (void)]
    [(_ (else form ...))
     (begin form ...)]
    [(_ (test form ...)
        more ...)
     (if test
         (begin form ...)
         (kond more ...))]))
```

Similarly, if you didn't have `if` you could write it in terms of `cond`: here's one called `yf` written in terms of `kond` using Scheme macros again:

```
(define-syntax yf
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ test result)
     (kond (test result))]
    [(_ test result otherwise)
     (kond (test result)
           (else otherwise))]))
```

Both of these may be variously buggy.

Historically, `cond` was the primitive I think.

Comment: on the first syntax/example that you stated, if all the condition was true in the nested if, shouldn't all the statement be printed?

Comment: @Zel: no, just the first thing that is true, as in `if (...) ...; else if (...) ...; else ...;` in C, say (except that `if` is an expression in Lisp as Lisp is an expression language: there are no statements, so `(+ (if x 1 2) 3)` is fine, say).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out.

```
(cond ((> 10 5)
    (format t "First numbers is greater. ~%")
    (< 10 15)
         (format t "Second number is greater. ~%")
         (= 10 10)
             (format t "Both numbers are equal. ~%")))
```

Comment: You have some misplaced parentheses here. You should have `(cond (test1 exp1 ...) (test2 exp2 ...))`, where the tests are like `(> 10 5)`. You can also add an `(else exp3 ...)` clause if you want.